# fluent nhibernate: compositeid() of same types, getting message no id mapped

Tags: nhibernate, fluent-nhibernate, many-to-many, composite-primary-key

I've scoured Google and SO but haven't come across anyone having the same problem. Here is my model:

```
public class Hierarchy
{
    public virtual Event Prerequisite { get; set; }
    public virtual Event Dependent { get; set; }

    public override bool Equals(object obj) 
    {
        var other = obj as Hierarchy; 
        if (other == null) 
        { 
            return false; 
        } 
        else 
        { 
            return this.Prerequisite == other.Prerequisite && this.Dependent == other.Dependent; 
        } 
    }

    public override int GetHashCode()
    {
        return (Prerequisite.Id.ToString() + "|" + Dependent.Id.ToString()).GetHashCode();
    }
}
```

Here is my mapping:

```
public class HierarchyMap : ClassMap<Hierarchy>
{
    public HierarchyMap()
    {
        CompositeId()
            .KeyReference(h => h.Prerequisite, "PrerequisiteId")
            .KeyReference(h => h.Dependent, "DependentId");
    }
}
```

And here is the ever present result:

```
{"The entity 'Hierarchy' doesn't have an Id mapped. Use the Id method to map your identity property. For example: Id(x => x.Id)."}
```

Is there some special configuration I need to do to enable composite id's? I have the latest FNh (as of 6/29/2012).

**Edit**

I consider the question open even though I've decided to map an Id and reference the 2 Event's instead of using a CompositeId. Feel free to propose an answer.

Comment: this looks good and a simple example of mine doesn't throw. are you sure you do not have another opr older Version of the map which doesn't have it mapped?

Comment: This is a new entity that I'm trying to UpdateSchema() on. I've double checked the dll versions. I'm trying to dig into the configuration defaults to see if there is something I need to override. But, per the Nhibernate source, "prefer a surrogate key to a composite key." So I just might give in forget the CompositeId altogether.

Comment: it is definitly better to use surrogate ids. However if you comment one keyreference, does it work better?

Comment: A clever test. =)  But it still wants Id mapped.

Comment: the ultimative test would be to map an Id property and see it fail again ^^

Comment: I'll just go with a separate Id and then reference the 2 events as suggested. Thanks!... Would still like to see a solution for this though. =)

Answer (score 0):

I figured out this was due to auto mapping trying to auto map the ID
Even though i had an actual map for my class - it still tried to auto map the ID.  Once i excluded the class from auto mapping, it worked just fine.